# Google Chrome error: failed to load, net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: php, google-chrome, typo3, content-length

With Chrome, I get always the error `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` and the page is blank. Other browsers like Firefox doesn't has that problem. I googled a lot but with no really luck.

It's a typo3 page which I recently moved. On the old server it worked without any problem.

I know the error means that the `Content-Length` which is submitted in the header does not match with the length which of the document / file, but I have no idea why and what I can do.

Does anyone has some advice?

Comment: The server is sending 'Content-Length: 36532` but the file is only `36429` bytes. Either it's a bug in the server, or your script is using `header('Content-length: something');` and that needs to be fixed.

Comment: try to found the log from server side, maybe a permission issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993826/err-content-length-mismatch-on-nginx-and-proxy-on-chrome-when-loading-large-file/76827595#76827595

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the Typoscript Setup

```
config.enableContentLengthHeader = 0
```

Comment: Very quick solution, will solve the issue! For those requiring a content-length header for whichever reason, see response below about causes for this problem and how to correct it (rather than work around it).

Answer (score 2):

This is just for completeness:

Look for any extension which is using the "feof" (frontend end-of-file) hook in page generation. If the content, which is already completely rendered at this point, changes size, the error above can occur. If the code that changes the content size is your own then you can also avoid this by sending a correct Content-Length header after you have modified the content. If the code is not your own then your only options are to deactivate the extension doing this - or set the `config.enableContentLengthHeader = 0` parameter like @bschauer says in the already accepted answer.